# Difference between get :index and get admin_categories_path in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, constraints

I'm testing my controller with rspec and run into an interesting problem.
I have my controller, `Admin::CategoriesController` with index action. I have restriction on the route:

```
resources :categories, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy] do
  collection do
    get ':kind', action: :index, as: '', kind: /(blog|news)/
  end
end
```

So, when I wrote spec on index:

```
it 'does not reply on not existing kind' do
  expect { get :index, kind: 'qwe' }.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
end
```

it passed. But then I decided to take the constraint of the routes:

```
class CategoryKindConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    %w(blog news).include? request.query_parameters['kind']
  end
end

get ':kind', action: :index, as: '', constraints: CategoryKindConstraint
```

and tests started to fail. No exception was raised.
But again - if I changed to:

```
expect { get admin_categories_path(kind: 'qwe') }.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
```

I got green result. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of tests do you write (feature/request or functional)?

In case of function (controller folder) you are in the scope of controller and you use `get :index`.

In case of feature or request test you are not in the scope of controller and you should use full path `user_path`.

Comment: I'm writing controller test. But as I said in question :index just give incorrect result